# TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition doesn't animate when activity first loads

Tags: android, android-animation, android-constraintlayout, android-transitions

I am using the constraintLayout with animations using TransitionManager.

I have the following 2 layouts

This is my `main_activity.xml`

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:text="Let's start animating"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is my `main_activity_alt.xml`

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

      <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:text="Let's start animating"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In my MainActivity I want to animate the image to slide upwards which would be the main_activity_alt.xml

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val constraintSet1 = ConstraintSet()
        constraintSet1.clone(constraintLayout)

        val constraintSet2 = ConstraintSet()
        constraintSet2.clone(this, R.layout.activity_main_alt)

        val transition = ChangeBounds()
        transition.duration = 5000

   val handler = Handler()
        handler.postDelayed({
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout, transition)
            constraintSet2.applyTo(constraintLayout)
        }, 10)
    }
```

When the above starts the image is already displayed. The `main_activity.xml` should hide and the `main_activity_alt.xml` will be its final resting place.

However, when the screens loads it just immediately displays the `imageview` without any animation

[image]

Anything I am doing wrong with the above?

Comment: I think first layout has to be rendered so you could animate transition to second one. Try to do animation after view is created not before

Comment: I have added the code to the onResume. However, the image always displays immediately.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionManager.html#beginDelayedTransition(android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.transition.Transition))  for *beginDelayedTransition*:

> Calling this method causes TransitionManager to capture current values in the scene root and then post a request to run a transition on the next frame. At that time, the new values in the scene root will be captured and changes will be animated.

You will have to wait until the layout is laid out before attempting the transition. There are a number of ways to do this, but the easiest would be to post the transition code as follows:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val constraintLayout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.constraintLayout)
    constraintLayout.post {
        val constraintSet1 = ConstraintSet()
        constraintSet1.clone(constraintLayout)
        val constraintSet2 = ConstraintSet()
        constraintSet2.clone(this, R.layout.activity_main2_alt)
        val transition = ChangeBounds()
        transition.duration = 5000
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout, transition)
        constraintSet2.applyTo(constraintLayout)
    }
}
```

Comment: actually, the click handler is not part of the problem, I just added it as a test, and removed it from my question. Actually, the problem is I want to animate the image to slide up when the activity starts.

Comment: @ant2009 OK. I'll repost.

Comment: Thanks, I have just posted an update to my question using a `Handler().postDelayed`. Not sure which would be better, but I like your idea of doing the `constraintLayout.post` I will make this as the correct answer.

Comment: @ant2009 postDelayed is a little overkill but should work. You just want to execute the transition code after the initial layout, so a simple post will do.

Comment: keep doing the lords work, thank you. saved me after days of troubleshooting.

Answer (score 5):

Try to make a delay to your transition so first layout would be inflated when transition starts

```
transition.delay = 300
```

if this wont work then try

`Handler().postDelayed({do transition here}, 300)`